# how to replace a property in a neo4j relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to NEO4j and Keetle etl.

Now I am trying to replace property value "costPerTon" in a relationship :COMPANY_COST_FOR_PRODUCT_{period}_{company}

I have the value calculated in Kettle and try to import them using Neo4j Cypher, but I don't know how to write this cypher...

should I use Merge or Set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MERGE` finds you the relationship (if it exists) , `SET` only sets a property on a relationship once you have found /created it.

For relationships, make are you first find the start and end nodes, once you have them

assuming you have found the  `(start)` and `(end)` nodes

you can do

```
// Find the rel, or create it if it does not yet exist
MERGE (start)-[r:MyRELTYPE]->(end)
// Set the property value
SET r.myProperty =  myPropertyValue
```

Comment: I see. Thank you! I also have another question: can I use Match to find the relationship?

Comment: MATCH finds patterns, which can contain both nodes sn relationships. see https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/match/